# Detecting a robot using Coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, user-agent

I need to simply detect if the visitor is a robot or a real browser.  I have the following code:

```
    <cfset REQUEST.UserAgent = LCase( CGI.http_user_agent ) />
    <cfif REFind( "bot\b", REQUEST.UserAgent ) OR 
    Find( "crawler", REQUEST.UserAgent ) OR 
    Find( "spider", REQUEST.UserAgent ) OR
    Find( "slurp", REQUEST.UserAgent ) OR
    Find( "mediapartners-google", REQUEST.UserAgent )> 
        <cfset notarobot = 0>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset notarobot = 1>
    </cfif>
```

Will this detects the common robots like MJ12bot, bingbot, slurp, googlebot, yandexbot, baiduspider etc.?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, it'd catch any request that uses a useragent that matches what you're looking for. it certainly wouldn't catch bots that aren't using those user agents, but it may catch non-bots that are.

Comment: I just want to distinguish legitimate bots vs a user.  What do you mean by it may catch non-bots?

Comment: you're just doing a simple usagent test. it's only as accurate as a useragent string is. It's likely "good enough" to accomplish your goals, assuming you aren't breaking the app for bots in the rare event a user browser happens to match one of the strings either today or years from now.

Comment: @KevinB perhaps you can suggest a better solution to distinguish SE bots from human visitors?

Comment: well, it depends on your goals. For example, I filter them out so i can end their sessions early, in which case using a useragent check such as yours works fine.

Comment: I suggest looking for a way to rewrite this so that you separate the data, user agents, from the programming code.

Comment: @DanBracuk Not sure what you mean by separate the data?  I simply need at a certain point to check if someone visiting this page is a robot or human.  If it is a robot, I will skip a block of code. Otherwise, I need to process that block. I am not looking at a catch-all-robots solution.  But just common SE crawling, I need to skip the block.

Comment: A cleaner way to write this would be to use a 'listFindNoCase' as well. Then you can have 1 if statement and 1 list variable and you don't have to worry about case.